# Redirect between HTTPS and HTTP with Non-standard ports using ASP.Net MVC 3 on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, iis-7

I've successfully deployed an MVC 3 web application to an IIS7 development server, with one hiccup. I'm using custom ports, since there is another application using the default port. This appears to break any redirect between http and https. I can manually enter the correct urls and go to the pages.

Example Redirect:

```
return this.RedirectToAction<SomeController>(x => x.Index());
```

Ideally, I'd like to get this working without the need for specialized or separate code for different deployments. Is there a web.config setting that I can use to fix this? Is there a standard fix, solution or configuration that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would run a web app on different ports. I would think that if the app has its own app pool, it would'nt matter.

In the past I have added this code to my project. 
Add this to your base controller just above the namespace.

```
#if !DEBUG
#define RELEASE
#endif
namespace YourProject.UI.Controllers
{
```

Add this just above your class declaration.

```
#if RELEASE
    [RequireHttps]
#endif
public abstract class YourProjectBaseController : Controller
{
```

Then make sure that all you controllers inherit from this base. The shortcut would be to just add the code above to the controller that contains your login information.

Comment: [URL Rewrite]http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/